# copy all spins / hashtags values to clipboard JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, copy-paste

im making a **function**  will **clipboard** each `<span class="tag">Value</span>` by **className**

When i tested it was fine on console but it's not copying anthing to clipboard, may i know the issue where exactly?

the code here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("copy_hashtags").addEventListener("click", copytags);
  function copytags() {
      var tags = document.querySelectorAll('.tag');
      var result = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
          result.push(tags[i].innerText);
      }
      result = result.join(' ');
      copyToClipboard(result);
       console.log(result);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: guess that depends on what the function `copyToClipboard` is - it's certainly not a standard function, so you must've either written it, or have some library that implements it - any error messages in the developer tools console?

Comment: post your implementation of copyToClipboard( ) function and if your goal is just to copy some string to clipboard, you can use `navigator.clipboard.writeText(yourText);`

Comment: @kulrajchavda it's solved the issue! instead of copyToClipboard(result) i used your navigator.clipboard.writeText(result); and it's works fine 100%. big thanks man